# Rails 3 Route Get No Route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am under Rails 3.0.9.

I have the route:

```
get 'account/index'
```

There are such information at console:

```
account_index GET    /account/index(.:format)   {:controller=>"account", :action=>"index"}
```

But when I try **http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/**,
 
I get **No route matches "/account"**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls refer to [Routes explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733101/understanding-rails-routes-match-vs-root-in-routes-rb) for a more detailed explanation. Also, the following line (match :to =>) should be at the top of your routes.rb file before `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`. Hope this helps.

```
match '/account', :to => 'account#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the route is /account/index and not /account
Try `get 'account#index'`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. But when I try **get 'account#index'** I get **missing :controller** error. But using **match 'account' => 'account#index', :via => :get** solves my problem. But it's not exectle what I need.

Answer (score 0):

@Lesha, I am relatively new to Rails as well. The following would be a much more generic way in your routes file instead of a get 'controller#action'.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

After this is done, you would have to access your page using http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/index

Comment: Sonu, thanks a lot for advise. But it is not suitable for me because I want to refer *http://127.0.0.1:3000/account* not *http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/index*

Comment: @LeshaPipiev, could you try the following after putting in the earlier suggestion in your routes.rb file ?

``match '/account', :to => 'account#index'`