# What will be my route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm working on Rails 3.

My URL is: http://localhost:3000/terms_and_conditions?val=pp

My method is below:

```
class GeneralController < ApplicationController

  def terms_and_conditions
    if !params[:val].nil?
      @val=params[:val]
    else
      @val='tc'
    end
  end

end
```

What will be my route? Please help me to create the route.

Comment: I do not understand "What will be my Route". Would you please expand your question?

Comment: I created this 
match 'terms_and_conditions' => 'general#terms_and_conditions' 
but now i got no route error

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first read the guides titled [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

To setup a simple GET accessible route add the following to your `routes.rb` file

`get "/terms_and_conditions" => "general#terms_and_conditions"`

If you need more than just GET, you can use `match` instead.  In your app root you can perform `rake routes` to see all the routes of your app as well.  With regards to your choice of exposing `/terms_and_conditions` — it would be better if you used a shorter path such as `/terms` and/or consider doing `/terms-and-conditions` instead.

Comment: I created this but now i got no route error
match 'terms_and_conditions' => 'general#terms_and_conditions'

Comment: There was a typo, make sure it is identical to the above.  Update your post with `rake routes` once you've added this to debug.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[YourAppNameHere]::Application.routes.draw do
match '/terms_and_conditions',    to: 'general#terms_and_conditions'
end
```

Comment: my url is http://localhost:3000/terms_and_conditions?val=pp
how I'll get value of val

Comment: Did you try 

``match '/terms_and_conditions', :to => 'general#terms_and_conditions`. Once the route matches, you can get the value of val using params[:val] in the controller or the view

You can try the following url for more explanation on routes.

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733101/understanding-rails-routes-match-vs-root-in-routes-rb[link]