# Rails Something is Wrong... (noob)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am a noob, and am learning from the book Beginning Ruby on Rails by Steve Holzner. He tells me to make a controller called hello_controller, edit the controller so it says

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
    def there
    end 
end
```

He then tells me to create a document called there.rhtml with some simple HTML in it, and to put it in the views/hello directory.
then, I launch the rails server, navigate to localhost:3000/hello/there, and the result of the HTML should appear on the page, 
I see:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/hello/there"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Comment: and the result of 'rake routes' is?

Comment: Also, you may want to check the date of the book you're reading -- if you're using `.rhtml` for your views you're on an ancient version of Rails (you know, maybe two years ago, or even longer!! :-).  Start with a book written for Rails 3.1 or higher -- a great deal has changed.

Comment: There is some great explanation on routes in another post on SO. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733101/understanding-rails-routes-match-vs-root-in-routes-rb]

Answer (score 5):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You need to add a route to the hello controller with the there action. The route's file is typically in

> config/route.rb

For example, if you add

```
match '/hello/there' => 'hello#there'
```

to your routes file, you should see that /hello/there will route to your correct controller and action. However, there are much more you need to know about routes than what I am showing you here, so please look through the link I gave you!

Answer (score 1):

For the quickest fix, try just typing the following url into your browser (note the ending):

```
localhost:3000/hello/there/0
```

Ken Li has given some good advice. Here's a bit of explanation: your routes file is probably defaulting to interpret only a select few routes after the pattern `/[controller_name]/[action_name]`, and 'there' isn't one of the few action names that it will recognize (until you change your routes.rb file). It should have a catch-all, however, for urls that follow the pattern `/[controller_name]/[action_name]/[id]`.

(Don't worry: your action doesn't actually need to do anything with the id at the end of the url. It's just that your rails app will recognize the pattern if the id is present.)