# Rails tutorial - Section 5.2 Routing/Rspec error

Tags: ruby, rspec, routes, railstutorial.org

Ruby newbie here. I'm following the Rails Tutorial and got stuck around 5.3 re: routes.

I have 5 pages(home, about, help, contact), all with similar test set, and rspec is only failing for the tests on 'home'. Since I'm using application_helper, I shouldn't need to specify  in home.html.erb, right? I also took the advise of [understanding rails routes: match vs root in routes.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733101/understanding-rails-routes-match-vs-root-in-routes-rb) and added "match '/static_pages/home' => 'static_pages#home'" to routes.db.

Been stuck on these 2 errors for a while. Please help. Thanks!

Errors:

```
1) Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sample App')
expected css "h1" with text "Sample App" to return something
# ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Static pages Home page should have the base title
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title',
expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" to return something
# ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

home.html.erb

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
<h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

<h2>
This is the home page for the
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
sample application.
</h2>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

  it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
    visit root_path
    page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sample App')
  end

  it "should have the base title" do
    visit root_path
    page.should have_selector('title', text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App")
  end

  it "should not have a custom page title" do
    visit root_path
    page.should_not have_selector('title', text: '| Home')
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

# Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
def full_title (page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
end

end
```

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact' 
  match '/static_pages/home' => 'static_pages#home'

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
end
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you removed the public/index.html file and visually verified that you can get to / in your browser, and that the expected template is being rendered? Your spec looks OK otherwise.

Comment: That's it. Thank you! I guess not removing public/index makes the controller perform the test on the default root (public/index.html) instead of home?

Comment: That's correct, capybara is simply requesting '/', just as you would yourself through the browser. Files in public/ take precedence over your rails routes, so the default index.html file will typically need to be removed when starting a new project. I think it has been discussed on the rails core mailing list that this should be made more apparent to newcomers - maybe it will make it into 4.0 :).